# How to record user interaction in Flash app?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I am looking for a way to capture the user interactions with a text input control in Flash over a period of time (not a screen cast)?
For example: If the user enter some text, then delete, then enter something, I would be able to store that interaction as it happens and replay that later. Any help would be extremely useful

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the [automation package](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/automation/package-detail.html) may be a good start. it only allows "playback" though. don't know about recording.

greetz
back2dos

Answer (score 0):

The big picture:

1. Detect any text changes in the field(s) watched. This is done using `onChanged` events.
2. Store info collected upon change in arrays or objects.
3. On playback, Timer -> increment an index -> read from arrays.